# Microsoft Bot Framework - Is there any way to restart a bot after it throws an error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I am building a bot in Microsoft Bot Framework which implements a series of branching waterfall dialogs. The thing is that some of these branches are still in development and some others are ready to test but when running the bot in Azure, if it encounters an error, it requires me to reset the whole service to be able to start talking to the bot again.

I wonder, is there is a way to programatically restart the service? (maybe some way of cleaning the dialog stack directly in my code when the following message prompts)

> The bot encounted an error or bug

Comment: You can publish it again, that will automatically reset your bot

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. What I want to accomplish is removing the need to republish the solution or restart the appservice in Azure.

Comment: Where are you throwing this error? It is in an onTurnError handler? In mine converstationState is deleted, essentially restarting the conversation. But the bot/app itself doesn't crash or freeze, so if that is happening to you, that's a different issue.

Comment: Are you testing the bot on a specific channel? Can you make use of [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) and test the bot locally and try setting breakpoints in your code to see what is causing the issue?